# "Cannot find or open the PDB file" in VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, debug-symbols, pdb-files

I see lots of questions and answers for this issue in Visual Studio, but no answers for VS Code.

It's really annoying to see about a hundred of these messages in between my WriteLines. Is there a way to fix this issue for VS Code? Full console output is below. As you can see, it mixes these warning messages with my debug statements and I have to manually scroll through it all every time I want to look at my output. VS Code doesn't have Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols, so I can't fix it the same way as Visual Studio. Any help to hide or fix these messages would be appreciated!

```
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with
Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software
to help you develop and test your applications.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Users\**USERNAME**\Documents\Projects\geckosync\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\gecko-sync.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Runtime.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Net.Http.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Net.Primitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Collections.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Console.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Users\**USERNAME**\.nuget\packages\newtonsoft.json\12.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\netstandard.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Private.Uri.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Threading.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Push Application

Loaded 'C:\Users\**USERNAME**\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore\2.2.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.ComponentModel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Users\**USERNAME**\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Linq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Users\**USERNAME**\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection\2.2.0\lib\netcoreapp2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Users\**USERNAME**\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Users\**USERNAME**\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.logging\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Linq.Expressions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Users\**USERNAME**\.nuget\packages\system.interactive.async\3.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Interactive.Async.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\remotion.linq\2.2.0\lib\netstandard1.0\Remotion.Linq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Users\**USERNAME**\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.abstractions\2.2.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Users\**USERNAME**\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.caching.memory\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Users\**USERNAME**\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.options\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Users\**USERNAME**\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.caching.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Users\**USERNAME**\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.primitives\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Data.Common.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Users\**USERNAME**\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relational\2.2.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Users\**USERNAME**\.nuget\packages\system.data.sqlclient\4.6.0\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.1\System.Data.SqlClient.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Users\**USERNAME**\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver\2.2.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Transactions.Local.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'. 
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Users\**USERNAME**\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Reflection.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Linq.Queryable.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Threading.Tasks.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Threading.Timer.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Threading.Thread.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Security.Claims.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Security.Principal.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.text.encoding.codepages\4.5.0\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.0\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe\4.5.1\lib\netcoreapp2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Private.Xml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.ObjectModel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Collections.Specialized.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Drawing.Primitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
{

  "api_key": "**REMOVED**",

  "data": {

    "item": 30,

    "min": {

      "value": 10

    },

    "max": {

      "value": 40

    }

  }

}

Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Net.Security.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Net.Sockets.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Threading.Overlapped.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Net.NameResolution.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Memory.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.8\System.Buffers.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
OK

{

  "api_key": "**REMOVED**",

  "data": [

    {

      "title": {

        "text": "Title1"

      },

      "label": null,

      "description": "Desc"

    },

    {

      "title": {

        "text": "Title2"

      },

      "label": null,

      "description": null

    },

    {

      "title": {

        "text": "Title3"

      },

      "label": {

        "name": "Label",

        "color": "#ffffff"

      },

      "description": "Desc"

    }

  ]

}

{

  "api_key": "**REMOVED**",

  "data": {

    "item": [

      {

        "value": "60000"

      },

      [

        "38594",

        "12000",

        "50000"

      ]

    ]

  }

}

The program '[4572] gecko-sync.dll' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the vscode you can add filter to the debugger console in the launch.json. Just add the following codes in your current configurations:

```
"logging": {
    "moduleLoad": false
}
```

Then the DLL Loaded messages should be gone!

Comment: I'm seeing that property is not allowed in my configuration.
Property logging is not allowed

Comment: Adding those lines drops the alerts on DLL's not found but I still cann't debug the code in VSCode.